# How to convert 4d RGB image data to 2d array for LogisticRegression

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have `train_dataset` 4d array holding 7000 RGB images (7000,299,299,3). Now I need to feed this dataset array to `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` for that it needs to be 2 dimensional.

I have tried::--

```
np.reshape(train_dataset[:],(7000, train_dataset.shape[1]*train_dataset.shape[2]))
```

results in ::--

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1877152797 into shape (7000,89401)
```

Can you please help in this reshaping of train_dataset array? I want maintain 7000 rows in train_dataset array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have only 6,999 images, sorry for your loss. The easiest is to let numpy calculate the missing shape for you

```
np.reshape(train_dataset, (6999, -1))
```

or more robustly

```
np.reshape(train_dataset, (train_dataset.shape[0], -1))
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. Kinda simple solution, #selfnote from now on a thumb rule always a quick look at official doc of API and then stackoverflow post.

Comment: Paul's answer is correct but this might still not be a good idea: by doing so your model will not be able to leverage the spatial organization of the features. I would strongly recommend to either do manual patch based feature extractions (e.g. using HoG, KMeans on patches...) to build a bag of visual words or use convolutional neural networks instead. Read up a some intro text book on Machine Learning for computer vision to learn more about this. The scikit-image documentation might also be of help.